# Register types using Unity in SPA (MvcControllers and WebApiControllers)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I create SPA application. So there are mvccontrollers and webApicontrollers.

I install Unity using Package Manager and register my services using Unity.

When i test it on MvcController - everything works. But when i start test it on WebApiController - i get error. After some research i found answer here : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

But now i have question-problem : where i should register my services - in UnityConfig file or in WebAPIConfig file or in both?

---

Registering of types in WebApiConfig :

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Registering of types in UnityConfig:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            // container.LoadConfiguration();

            container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only create one single Unity container, this way, you will have to register your services in one single place.

I would suggest registering everything in UnityConfig, and then changing WebApiConfig to use the existing container instead of creating a new one.

Replace the 3 lines you you mention in your question by this single line :

```
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
```